# how to get iphone 4.1 HDR frames

Tags: iphone

Is there way to problematically get individual bracketed shots from iphone 4.1 HDR photo instead of a single HDR'ed photo?

Comment: Im not sure the question is clear enough to be answered. What is a bracketed shot? And do you mean programatically?

Comment: @twerdster - For high-dynamic-range (HDR) photos, multiple images are taken at varying exposures that bracket the original exposure level.  These are then pieced together to create the final HDR photo.  On iOS 4.1, this is done automatically by the system.  What he's asking is if there is a way for an application to access each of the original images that were taken at different exposure levels to create the composite HDR image, instead of just getting back the final image from the photo library.

Comment: @Brad - thanks. Didnt know that was its name. I would hazard the guess that its not possible considering that the HDR is produced by Apple and not by any public API's. I think for bob it would be simpler to activate the camera 3 times with different exposures then try to get direct access.